# Using statsmodels.seasonal_decompose() without DatetimeIndex but with Known Frequency

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I have a time-series signal I would like to decompose in Python, so I turned to statsmodels.seasonal_decompose(). My data has frequency of 48 (half-hourly). I was getting the same error as [this questioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457281/decomposing-trend-seasonal-and-residual-time-series-elements), where the solution was to change from an Int index to a DatetimeIndex. But I don't know the actual dates/times my data is from.

In [this github thread](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3225), one of the statsmodels contributors says that

> "In 0.8, you should be able to specify freq as keyword argument to
>   override the index."

But this seems not to be the case for me. Here is a minimal code example illustrating my issue:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
dta = pd.Series([x%3 for x in range(100)])
decomposed = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(dta, freq=3)

AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq'
```

Version info:

```
import statsmodels
print(statsmodels.__version__)
0.8.0
```

Is there a way to decompose a time-series in statsmodels with a specified frequency but without a DatetimeIndex?

If not, is there a preferred alternative for doing this in Python? I checked out the Seasonal package, but [its github](https://github.com/welch/seasonal) lists 0 downloads/month, one contributor, and last commit 9 months ago, so I'm not sure I want to rely on that for my project.

Comment: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3503  This is currently a bug in 0.8. Workaround: use numpy arrays in the function call if there is no time index.

Comment: Hi Josef, I filed that issue, thanks a lot for the detailed responses on github. Happy to continue to follow this there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to josef-pkt for answering this on github. There is a bug in statsmodels 0.8.0 where it always attempts to calculate an inferred frequency based on a DatetimeIndex, if passed a Pandas object.

The workaround when using Pandas series is to pass their values in a numpy array to `seasonal_decompose()`. For example:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

my_pandas_series = pd.Series([x%3 for x in range(100)])
decomposed = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(my_pandas_series.values, freq=3)
```

(no errors)