# Python-Pandas - AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq'-

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, statsmodels

I am trying to run

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose 

series = Series.from_csv("sugar_price_2.csv", header=0, sep=";", parse_dates=[0])

results = seasonal_decompose(series, model='additive')
```

This is Giving an Errror

> "AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq'"

Cant Figure Out what's the issue, please help,

Also , please Help me with the Date parsing if needed as The dates are in - 
"" dd-mm-yy " format

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and expected output for the users to help you precisely. :) Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `series = series = Series....`? As far as dates are concerned, looks like your dates can be interpreted via `%m-%d-%y`

Comment: Your time series data do not have a clear frequency like either the data is collected hourly or minutely or daily or monthly or yearly or some fixed frequency. Please check if this the issue.

Comment: I have edited @rahlf23 , it was a typo.

Comment: @rahlf23 ,
How shall i convert my Date Index to %m-%d-%y?

Comment: @anky_91 - here is the file link- https://files.fm/u/d7cnthrf#sign_up 
Its a Time series forecasting mate, Completely Unsupervised learning

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - Its collected daily for a timespan of 1 year almost... Now please tell hwat should I do to use  seasonal_deompose()

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425774/using-statsmodels-seasonal-decompose-without-datetimeindex-but-with-known-freq/42445953#42445953):  `seasonal_decompose(series.values, freq=3)`.

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf When I run this it showing 



["F:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\filters\filtertools.py:28: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  return np.r_[[np.nan] * head, x, [np.nan] * tail]" ]

Answer (score 0):

For date parsing use below code

```
parse_dates['DATE'] = series['DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y%m')
```