# Python StatsModels Time Series Decomposition Duplicate Plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I am using a mixture of [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and [StatsModels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/) to plot a time series decomposition. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672236/time-series-decomposition-function-in-python/28284962#28284962) but when I call `plot()` it seems to be plotting a duplicate.

My `DataFrame` looks like

[image]

My index looks like

[image]

but when I plot the decomposition I get this

[image]

Strangely, if I plot only an element of the decomposition, the duplication does not occur

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assign the result of `res.plot()` to something, e.g. `fig = res.plot()`.
The result of that method is a `matplotlib.figure`. The duplicate is from it's `_repr_html_`, which the notebook renders since it's the last item in the cell. You can try it yourself with

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2], [1, 2])
fig
```

The second method returns a matplotlib `axes`, which doesn't have a `_repr_html` so you just see that text above the figure.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `plt.show()` line after Solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ";" end of plotting code.
`res.plot();`

Comment: Consider writing this as a comment. Also, generally using semicolons is discourages in python.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why a semi-colon can solve the duplication problem?